# Binding A HashMap Instance In Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have a method that returns a Map():

```
private Map<String, Catalog> readCatalogFromXml(String xmlFile) {
    // blah blah read XML via DOM
}
```

However, I need to bind the results of that call to a single instance to be injected into multiple classes. I've been looking over the docs for MapBinder but am confused. I'm probably missing something simple, can anyone assist?

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the returned Map injected, I would ...

1. define a subclass "@Singleton public class MyInjectedMap extends HashMap { }"
2. bind a Provider < MyInjectedMap > to produce instances

Answer (score 4):

Just implement a provider in your Module class:

```
public class ModuleImpl extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // bind whatever needed
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Map<String, Catalog> provideMap(@XMLFile String xmlFile) {
        // create an instance of your class
        return myClass.readCatalogFromXml(xmlFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Search the docs for "Provider Methods" for more examples of this.  If you require, provider methods can take the @Singleton annotation.

Comment: @Darren Thanks, I'm just a Guice Newbie, so didn't know about the Singleton annotation. I'll add this.

Comment: late to the party, how can we provide Map<String, Catalog> as eager singleton?